# Show reasons for deleting a question

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, deleted-questions, vote-to-delete, vote-to-undelete

When questions are closed, they're closed for a stated reason: too broad, off topic, etc. But when a question is deleted, there's no reason stated on the question page. Why is this? It makes it difficult to know whether the reason for deletion was a good one.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39247438/new-datelong-parselongdate-does-not-correctly-parse-timestamp-stringjava/39247522#39247522) is a good example. It was closed as a dupe; it was then deleted. It's really not clear to me why it was deleted, since it's policy to leave duplicates in place to assist searching.

Could we please require a reason from those who vote to delete a question, and show that reason on the question page?

(I realise that only 10K+ users will be able to see the question and the reason, but they're the ones who need to be determining whether to undelete it in any case.)

Comment: Clearly that was deleted because it doesn't add a helpful signpost to an existing issue. Had the OP done any research at all in the first place, they'd have found the dupe using the exact terms in their question. Therefore it has no value.

Comment: I think this could be a good idea. With regard to this question: it's policy to leave *good* duplicates. Of the 3 answers on this question: 2 are very poor and misleading (one is suggesting to add 0's with no explanations, the other is a code-only that does not even address the problem), only the last one (yours) would be of value. That said, the question itself shows absolutely no research and it was asked and answered [a lot of times](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=long+to+date+%5Bjava%5D+is%3Aq). All in all, it isn't a question to keep.

Comment: (You may want to find another example, because I don't believe the current one properly supports your question.) What possible options would you like to see? "[x] This question is obsolete because there are tons of close duplicates" ... and?

Comment: I do not have 10K, still working on hit, but I definitely do not choose if to reopen a question based on the close reason, I don't care. If question is on-topic I will reopen vote, if not I will not (no sense re-opening and closing only because I don't agree with close reason). To me the banner serves to help OP, so if delete reason should be added I think the spirit should be the same. Thus the question becomes, does it help the OP?, probably not.

Comment: There is no choice when one votes to delete to my knowledge. What kind of "reason" you are looking to expose here? Or you are asking for new feature to allow deletion reasons in a first place?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think this is needed. For the vast majority of questions, the delete reason is the same as the close reason. In the case of duplicates, which you rightly state are normally not to be deleted, the reason for deletion is that the duplicate doesn't add anything worth preserving that's not in the original. This is the case in the example you linked to. The person who asked that question doesn't seem to have done any research whatsoever, so that question doesn't even provide a useful signpost to lead people to the original question. They can just go directly there from a simple search.

It might be a good idea to make people stop and think whether or not they're deleting a question for the right reason, particularly on duplicates, but I don't think it should be required unless you can show that a lot of questions are being deleted that shouldn't be.