# Why not provide a reason to vote to undelete?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When we vote to close a question we have multiple choices. When we vote for deleting a question according to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333811/1997376), it is not needed to provide a reason as it is mostly for the same reason as the question has been closed (I don't totally agree but it is another subject).

But my question is **why not leaving the ability to explain a vote for undeleting a question** because some times the context is not obvious and needs to be explained more for a better moderation. The provided arguments could be considered as not good enough by people reading them but at least they will have everything needed to take the best possible decision.

---

**EDIT:** The scope of this feature request is not limited to any particular reason of deletion, a question could be abusively deleted by peers but also by the OP (in case of an assignment for example as the OP doesn't want to leave any trace that he did not do it by himself) or by the system (due to a bug for example). For all the examples listed previously and many others it could be interesting to explain our undelete vote as it cannot be explained just with a simple click to vote.

Comment: Why would someone not read the comments before voting to undelete, or refraining?

Comment: Whether Brian Goetz, Jon Skeet or Eric Lippert has commented on a question does not matter at all for deletion/undeletion. What matters is the quality of the posts, not the authors, and comments are second-class citizens anyway.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: "comments disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews". The **only** way to bring a deleted question to the attention of potential undeleters is to raise it on Meta. Being a mere dabbler in Java, I find nothing delete-worthy in Nicolas' example question - even though it may be a duplicate.

Comment: @RadLexus: Right, right, it's been too long since I had 10k on ELL. (Although really, the point you're making about attention is less about choosing reasons -- reopen doesn't get any -- and more about e.g. having a queue.)

Comment: The post has been undeleted.

Comment: @Nicolas I just mentioned that it was undeleted. There was nothing else that was implied by that comment.

Comment: Nicolas, is this a better title? I agree that for *some* (very few!) questions I was unable to see why it got deleted. Your example was one, and its prompt un-deletion kind of supports this.

Comment: If you're only using it an an example, why link to it and make it the longest paragraph of the question? But, since when are we voting to delete / undelete based on _comments_? [They don't work like that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work). Fair, it's a comment by an Oracle architect... which would be more valuable if written on the original question having all the views, and the links to it (since it's more linked to, more chance of being seen/read).

Comment: There may be nothing "wrong" with the question other than the downvoter [disagrees with it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) or they've [still not found their keys](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/188189)

Comment: @RobertLongson thx for the links, I was not aware of that. However even if people disagree they can still explain why

Comment: First require a reason for downvoting, then fight this battle

Comment: Err... you know how many posts are deleted by "users" that are not the "OP"? [~1 per cent of all deleted posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296609/792066), now you know how many are deleted by the system? ~39%. How many are deleted by their own authors? ~36%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the feature request is obviously globally rejected by the SO community, please note that even if it is not an ideal approach as it should rather be managed directly by the undelete queue's reviewers, as workaround for such particular cases, we can still flag the deleted question and explain the problem to the moderators.

Comment: is the idea to undelete delete questions withz zero reputation good idea?